listOf, immutableListOf, objectListOf
I know the listOf is from the kotlin collections and we usually use that.
listOf(1,2,3)

When I started developing in Compose I learned about the Immutable Kotlin collections library and been using it when i need a list of somethings in my state so it becomes stable
persistentListOf(Venue(....), Venue(....),...)

But recently I discovered the androidx.collection library but I do not find any really great source on when I should use it, where should I use it and how should i use it?
Is it a replacement for persistentListOf() ?
What are the use cases?


Is it a replacement for persistentListOf() ?

No, insofar as AFAIK none of the androidx.collection types will be treated as immutable by the Compose Compiler. androidx.collection mostly is a bunch of specialized collection types for primitive values, plus a few for specific scenarios (e.g., SieveCache for caching).
